# How to prove $f(x+1) = g(x)$ is equivalent to $f(x) = g(x-1)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to prove $f(x+1) = g(x)$ is equivalent to $f(x) = g(x-1)$,
given that both $f(x)$ and $h(x)$ are defend on $\mathbb{R}$.

To me this statement is very intuitive, but I don't know how to justify this rigorously.
I would appreciate any helps and comments.

Comment: It may help to fix a particular value for which you wish to prove one statement or the other and be clear about quantifiers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and define $y=x-1\in\mathbb{R}$. If $f(x+1)=g(x)$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then, in particular it is true for $y=x-1$, which implies that
$$f(x)=f(x-1+1)=f(y+1)=g(y)=g(x-1).$$

Answer (score 4):

$$f(x+1)=g(x)$$

$$y=x-1$$

$$f(y+1)=g(y)$$

$$f(x)=g(x-1)$$